# Groovy Converting List of objects to Comma Separated Strings

Tags: groovy

I have a groovy list of CurrencyTypes 
example

```
class CurrencyType
{
    int id;
    def code;
    def currency;
    CurrencyType(int _id, String _code, String _currency)
    {
        id = _id
        code = _code
        currency = _currency
    }
}

def currenciesList = new ArrayList<CurrencyType>()
currenciesList.add(new CurrencyType(1,"INR", "Indian Rupee"))
currenciesList.add(new CurrencyType(1,"USD", "US Dollar"))
currenciesList.add(new CurrencyType(1,"CAD", "Canadian Dollar"))
```

I want the list of codes as comma separated values like INR, USD, CAD with minimal code and with out creating new list.

Comment: @dmahapatro it was the first response I got, I tried it and it worked

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try `currenciesList.code.join(", ")`. It will create list at background, but it's minimal code solution.

Also do you know, that your code may be even Groovier? Look at [Canonical](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Canonical.html) or [TupleConstructor](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html) transformations.

```
//This transform adds you positional constructor.
@groovy.transform.Canonical 
class CurrencyType {
  int id
  String code
  String currency
}

def currenciesList = [
     new CurrencyType(1,"INR", "Indian Rupee"),
     new CurrencyType(1,"USD", "US Dollar"),
     new CurrencyType(1,"CAD", "Canadian Dollar")
]

//Spread operation is implicit, below statement is same as
//currenciesList*.code.join(/, /)
currenciesList.code.join(", ")
```

Comment: Tried to make it more groovier. I don't understand why this answer was not accepted.

Comment: You win some, you lose some.

Comment: It would be interesting to get used to `currenciesList*.code`, since automatic list expansion will [probably be removed](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GroovyJSR/GEP+11+-+Groovy+3+semantics+and+new+MOP#GEP11-Groovy3semanticsandnewMOP-Removingautomaticlistexpansion)

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to create a new list (which you say you don't want to do), you can use `inject`

```
currenciesList.inject( '' ) { s, v ->
    s + ( s ? ', ' : '' ) + v
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This one works as well:

```
    String s = ""
    currenciesList.collect { s += "$it.code,"  }

    assert s == "INR,USD,CAD,"
```

Comment: See this is where using `join` is the smart way to go, to avoid the trailing `,`. ;)